# Delphi memory leak when adding language

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe

Delphi XE, Windows 7 64-bit

When you add language support to an empty application you will receive a memory leak (FastMM4).

How to reproduce:

- create new VCL forms Application
- modify the .dpr and add `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;`
- Build/Run the application and close the application -> no leaks reported
- now add a language (Project -> Languages -> Add)
- Build/Run again and close the application -> Memory leak??

FastMM4 full debug mode report:

```
--------------------------------2013/7/16 14:54:34--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 12

This block was allocated by thread 0x17EC, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
40455E 
40952D 
4094C8 
409834 
409941 
450058 
74548D76 [Unknown function at FirstHookFunc]
7778FA1A [ZwOpenKey]
75924033 [OpenRegKey]
759240AE [OpenRegKey]
777FA71A [Unknown function at RtlUlonglongByteSwap]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown

The allocation number is: 6

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EF9A610:
6E 00 6C 00 2D 00 42 00 45 00 00 00 41 58 0D 7A 00 00 00 00 C1 A6 F9 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2E 00 00 00 5E 45 40 00 DD 99 40 00 6D 71 4B 00 98 65 40 00 04 66 40 00
77 A6 40 00 98 7C 4B 00 AA 33 8D 76 F2 9E 7A 77 C5 9E 7A 77 00 00 00 00 EC 17 00 00 EC 17 00 00
1F 9A 40 00 53 7F 42 00 2C 65 40 00 EA 68 40 00 E3 7C 4B 00 AA 33 8D 76 F2 9E 7A 77 C5 9E 7A 77
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B6 5C 27 4D 5C 12 4C 00 80 80 80 80
49 A3 D8 B2 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 F9 B7 F9 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
65 00 00 00 5E 45 40 00 A7 50 40 00 22 56 40 00 DC 50 40 00 5F 72 4B 00 78 96 44 00 8E 72 4B 00
98 65 40 00 04 66 40 00 77 A6 40 00 98 7C 4B 00 EC 17 00 00 EC 17 00 00 7A 45 40 00 C5 50 40 00
n  .  l  .  -  .  B  .  E  .  .  .  A  X  .  z  .  .  .  .  Á  ¦  ù  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ^  E  @  .  Ý  ™  @  .  m  q  K  .  ˜  e  @  .  .  f  @  .
w  ¦  @  .  ˜  |  K  .  ª  3    v  ò  ž  z  w  Å  ž  z  w  .  .  .  .  ì  .  .  .  ì  .  .  .
.  š  @  .  S    B  .  ,  e  @  .  ê  h  @  .  ã  |  K  .  ª  3    v  ò  ž  z  w  Å  ž  z  w
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ¶  \  '  M  \  .  L  .  €  €  €  €
I  £  Ø  ²  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  ù  ·  ù  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
e  .  .  .  ^  E  @  .  §  P  @  .  "  V  @  .  Ü  P  @  .  _  r  K  .  x  –  D  .  Ž  r  K  .
˜  e  @  .  .  f  @  .  w  ¦  @  .  ˜  |  K  .  ì  .  .  .  ì  .  .  .  z  E  @  .  Å  P  @  .

--------------------------------2013/7/16 14:54:34--------------------------------
This application has leaked memory. The small block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered by pointer):

5 - 12 bytes: Unknown x 1

Note: Memory leak detail is logged to a text file in the same folder as this application. To disable this memory leak check, undefine "EnableMemoryLeakReporting".
```

Now to the funny part: remove the language and run again -> the leak stays!

I can remove the leak by deleting all project related files (.dproj, .dproj2007, .dsk and so on..) except the .dpr and .res files.

Can someone explain me what is going on?

**UPDATE**

Using the addresses from the detail log, it seems I found the leak in System.Pas:

```
var
  PreferredLanguagesOverride: PChar = nil;

...    
procedure SetLocaleOverride(const NewPreferredLanguages: string);
var
  L: Integer;
begin
  if PreferredLanguagesOverride <> nil then
    FreeMem(PreferredLanguagesOverride);
  L := Length(NewPreferredLanguages);
  if L > 0 then
  begin
    Inc(L);
    GetMem(PreferredLanguagesOverride, L * SizeOf(Char));
    MoveChars(NewPreferredLanguages[1], PreferredLanguagesOverride^, L);
  end;
end;
```

SetLocaleOverride is called and reserves memory for the `PreferredLanguagesOverride` `PChar`. I scanned System.Pas for `FreeMem(PreferredLanguagesOverride)` but this is the only occurrence!

**UPDATE2**

I found the reason why delphi calls the `SetLocaleOverride` routine:

when you add language support, a registry key is created with the name as the executable full path and the current system locale as value:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\Locales

Deleting this key prevents delphi from calling the `SetLocaleOverride` routine.

Question:

- can someone verify if this problem exists in later Delphi versions? (or else I make a QC report)

**UPDATE 3**

there is already a  [QC report (105136)](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105136) and it has been fixed from XE3

Question: can someone show me how this has been patched in XE3?

Comment: Submit a QC report, and call RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Delphi XE3, Windows 7 64-bit...

Comment: @Tlama: thanks, apparently it has been fixed in your version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in my question, this is fixed from XE3.

For those with lower versions, you can patch System.pas.

Add `SetLocaleOverride('');` in the `procedure _Halt0` just before the line:

```
FinalizeUnits;
```

This will get rid of the memory leak.

Good to know: [How to recompile System.pas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842026/800214).

If you don't want to recompile System.pas, you can call `SetLocaleOverride('');` in a `finalization` section.