# how to build custom system.pas in delphi to create system.dcu?

Tags: delphi

I made some changes in Delphi Ide's system.pas file.

Now I want to build it to create its dcu. Is there a way to build it?

I tried all ways including custom system.pas file in packages, with console, 
but they show 'redeclare system unit'.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: See [Recompiling the RTL - if possible, then how?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4839532/576719). There should be a buildrtl.bat file as well.